# Show that a positive symmetric half-identical matrix has a Cholesky factorisation

Tags: math

Using the maximum rank decomposition, show that a positive symmetric half-identical matrix has a Cholesky factorisation.

I have searched in my books but none of them showed the steps and all the explanations. Please help me find the demostration.

Comment: This is a good question, but not for stackoverflow. I believe it will be well-received on https://math.stackexchange.com/